# "OK glass" works, "*My list item*" doesnt

Tags: android, google-glass

I am trying to develop an app for Google Glass, but somehow the voice commands don't work with my app.

Starting other apps and using voice menus in other 3rd party apps works just fine, but I somehow can't get it working.

This is my "my_voice_trigger.xml":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<trigger keyword="test app">
    <constraints camera="true" />
</trigger>
```

and I also added this to the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.glass.permission.DEVELOPMENT" />
<application...
    <activity...
        <intent-filter...
            <action android:name="com.google.android.glass.action.VOICE_TRIGGER" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
       </intent-filter></activity>...
```

It compiles without errors and never crashes.

The app is shown in the "OK glass"-launcher menu and I can use "OK glass" to bring up my menus in the app, but I can not select an item or start my app.

Answer (score 0):

OK..

**First** I had to move the app and item titles to the strings.xml for [unlisted commands](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/voice#unlisted_commands).

**Second** I had to connect glass to the internet and try every voice command before they worked offline.